# PostgreSQL replication role without permission to see or delete other replication slots

Tags: postgresql, transactional-replication, pg-logical

We have a PostgreSQL server with multiple databases for different projects. We want to use logical replication on those databases so the applications receive all the changes for their replication slot and publication. Their (or one of their) database roles requires the "replication" permission.

They can only read data from the database for which the replication/publication was created. But this permission enables them to delete any replication slot on the database server - also those that do not "belong" to their database.

Is there any way to grant a user only the ability to receive WAL messages - but not the permission to delete/see other replication slots?

Comment: I don't think that is possible today.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but thanks for confirming this!